# Create stored procedure inside try-catch block

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I'm using sqlserver 2014 and trying to create a `StoredProcedure` inside try-catch block like this:

```
BEGIN TRY   
  CREATE PROCEDURE [ammeghezi1] (@w INT) AS SELECT '' 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ...
END CATCH
```

It fails to run with the error of: `Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT' Expecting EXTERNAL.`
Then i changed sp like: `CREATE PROCEDURE [ammeghezi1] (@w INT) AS BEGIN SELECT '' END` (cover sp with BEGIN-END block), But the error did not change. I also add `GO` after `BEGIN TRY` statement and it just got worst.
I'm getting to conclude that creating `sp` inside `TRY_CATCH` block is not practical.

**Is this even possible to create `sp` inside `TRY_CATCH` block? And how?**

Comment: Have you tried creating the procedure without the try-catch block?

Comment: Why do you want the create statement in a try catch? What error are you trying to handle? I can understand the try catch inside the procedure but can’t see a reason for it on a create

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`CREATE PROCEDURE` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql):

> The CREATE PROCEDURE statement cannot be combined with other
>   Transact-SQL statements in a single batch.

If you need a try/catch, you'll need to execute the DDL using dynamic SQL so that it is in a separate batch:

```
BEGIN TRY   
    DECLARE @CreateProcedureStatement nvarchar(MAX) =
N'CREATE PROCEDURE [ammeghezi1] (@w INT) AS SELECT ''''';
    EXEC sp_executesql  @CreateProcedureStatement;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question, but I sense a bad practice here (this is a SQL developer perspective, not a DBA one). Why would you do that?

If you the procedure must be created only it does not exist, just [check for its existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072086/how-to-check-if-a-stored-procedure-exists-before-creating-it):

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
            FROM   sysobjects 
            WHERE  id = object_id(N'[dbo].[MyProc]') 
                   and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1 )
```

The context of how this is run is not specified, but it might be important. If this is part of a deployment process, typically it is a good idea to let the exception (execution error) bubble and handle it outside SQL.

While having the stored procedure executed as a dynamic SQL works, I would advice against it: it is way harder to write its creation as a string, it looks awful (way less readable) and all the parsing errors will be moved to run time.